# scala self type trait instantiation

Tags: scala

Trait in scala is something like interface in Java or abstract class. Thus it is not possible to get an instance directly from a trait. But, I found a way to instantiate a trait. Here is what i do:

```
trait B {
  def bId = 1
}

trait A { self: B =>
  def aId = 2
}

val a = new A with B // The type of a is "A with B", a's value is $anon$1@6ad16c5d
```

and the following:

```
trait User {
  def name: String
}

trait DummyUser extends User {
  override def name: String = "foo"
}

trait Tweeter { self: User =>
  def tweet(msg: String) = println(s"$name: $msg")
}

val t = new Tweeter with User // This doesn't compile
val t = new Tweeter with User with DummyUser // This does work!
// t: Tweeter with User with DummyUser = $anon$1@72976b4
t.tweet("hello")  // result is: "foo: hello"
```

Both segments of code are working on Scala 2.12. In the all of them, there are only traits! No class at all.

How can trait work in this way?

Comment: It's actually much simpler than that. `new B {}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This instantiation like **Java**'s [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) instantiation, so when `new Tweeter with User` it's actually create a new **anonymous instance** for `Tweeter with User` **Anonymous Classes**.

And `new Tweeter with User` for this not compile, since it's losing the implementation of `name` method. actually you need to implement it like:

```
  val t = new Tweeter with User {
    override def name: String = "hello world"
  }
```

for `new Tweeter with User with DummyUser` you just need to state it as  `new Tweeter with DummyUser`, Since `DummyUser` is subtype of `User`.

And there is a [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) in **Scala** for how to use **self type** to implement **Dependency Injection**.

Comment: So is "new A with B" just a syntactic sugar for "new Object extends A with B"? Or, like the use of case class?

Comment: @JeffXu Yes,  it creates a new class(Anonymous Classes) that `extends` from `A` and `B`.